# Kubernetes deployment name changes after every deployment of stream from spring cloud data flow

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

i have a stream source application Name : app1
Stream Name : Stream1
After First deployment, deployment name is Stream-app1-v1
After second deployment, deployment name is Stream-app1-v2

can one please explain how the names are changing?
i'm trying to autoscale the source based on deployment kind.

Answer (score 0):

If you need Pods to have consistent names, then you should use a StatefulSet.

See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

They're pretty much like Deployment or DeploymentConfigs, though there is no object versioning, no rollback possible. StatefulSets are more suited for stateful workloads such as clustered databases.

Answer (score 0):

SCDF uses Skipper server to manage the continuous delivery of the streaming applications. Every time you upgrade/rollback an existing application of the stream, that app gets updated with an incremental version name in the suffix. There is a related discussion around this here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-skipper/issues/953